# Call to undefined method Stringy\Stringy::indexOfLast()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, require

The following method in my model causes above error:

```
public function getThumbnailUrlAttribute()
{
    $thumb = S::create($this->attributes['thumbnail_url'], 'UTF-8');
    return $thumb->insert('thumb', $thumb->indexOfLast('/', 0));
}
```

I use [`Stringy`](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy) package above in the same method:

```
use Stringy\Stringy as S;
```

In my Laravel 5 project i try to modify thumbnail image link before echoing it in blade. I'm stuck in this silly matter.

Comment: Can you check if you have the indexOfLast method on the Stringy\Stringy class you are referencing?

Comment: Yes, of course : [link to indexOfLast method](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy/blob/master/src/Stringy.php#L924)

Comment: There is a indexOfLast method for Stringy 1.9.0, not for 1.8.0. Can you verify if you are using 1.9.0?

Comment: Well, I `require: { "danielstjules/stringy": "~1.9" }` in `composer.json`.

Comment: Try checking if the method exists programatically...  `$s = new S('test'); $clazz = new \ReflectionClass($s); var_dump($clazz->getMethods());`  That should give you an array of all the methods on the class.

Comment: @user3158900 You're right, the method is not listed there - but still - how do i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously said version 1.9.0 had that method. I was wrong. They are available only to the master/dev version.

Update your package to dev version.

Composer.json
`require: { "danielstjules/stringy"}`

And run composer update.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I tried do that, but my composer just freezed - for an hour or two, and sec ago said there's nothing to update. I ended up with downloading files from github Stringy rep and just pasting it to my project folder.

Comment: I tried to do `"danielstjules/stringy": "1.x-dev",`, and - among other -  I got message, that laravel requires version 1.8, could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes. Laravel composer.json has a require for "danielstjules/stringy": "~1.8". Do you really need the IndexOfLast method? Won't $thumb->length() work for you?

Comment: Well, I could even copy or make this method - but I like to use, what I already have, as Laravel had this package. And it works - for now.